# Cruise Control .Net exception writing msbuild-results.xml

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, ccnet-config

I have a cruise control server running a build on a VM.  All I did was change the source control from Perforce to Git, and the build is now failing.

**CCNet Config**

```
<tasks>
    <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>c:\Build\Pcp_Main</workingDirectory>
        <buildArgs>/v:d Pcp.proj /target:Clobber;Build /property:Configurations="Debug;Release" /property:NUnitRedirectConsoleOutput=1</buildArgs>
        <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
        <timeout>2700</timeout>
    </msbuild>
</tasks>
```

**Build Log**

```
Done Building Project "c:\Build\Pcp_Main\Pcp.proj" (Clobber;Build target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:01:32.39
MSBUILD : error MSB4015: The build stopped unexpectedly because the "ReusableLogger"   logger failed unexpectedly during shutdown.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path  'c:\Build\Pcp_Main\Artifacts\msbuild-results-2d082e8c-0e88-4c0b-9a6b-aa0e3094cab9.xml'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.XmlLogger.Shutdown()
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.ReusableLogger.Shutdown()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService.ShutdownLogger(ILogger logger)
</build>
```

The folder c:\Build\Pcp_Main\Artifacts\ exists and the user running the build has write access to the folder.

I have also tried changing the logging dll to Rodemeyer.MsBuildToCCnet.dll and I get the same exception.

The project also builds from the command line without any problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was having the artifacts folder inside the build folder.  Moving it outside of the build folder resolved the issue.

Comment: was searching all over stackoverflow for this error but couldn't find a solution. Now I found it myself and been searching for something else... and found this... when life gives you lemons.....

Comment: Glad this helped someone!

Comment: We were getting this because at the beginning of our build we were cleaning up a previous build, which included the MSBuild log file were were writing to. Oops.